# How can I encode a class into a C# Hashtable?

Tags: c#, class, hashtable

I am using someone else library that converts `Hashtable` and `ArrayList` to JSON. I want to use regular `List<T>` with this library so need to transform such lists into `ArrayList`.

Say I have a class like the following:

```
public class Foo
{
     public int MyInt;
     public string MyString;
     public List<float> MyList;
}
```

How do I transform an instance of this class into a `Hashtable` where the keys of the Hashtable are the class variable names, and the values of the Hashtable are the values of the instance?  In addition, I would like to encode any `List<T>` class variables as `ArrayList` in this `Hashtable`.

I've attempted this start:

```
private Hashtable convertModelInstanceToHashtable<T>(T instance)
{
    Hashtable encodedTable = new Hashtable();
    var fieldNames = typeof(T).GetFields()
                              .Select(field => field.Name)
                              .ToList();

    foreach(var fieldName in fieldNames)
    {
        var encodedValue = fieldName.GetValue(instance);

        // NEED HELP HERE: statement for type to convert
        // List<T> to ArrayList

        encodedTable.Add(fieldName.ToString(), encodedValue);
    }

    return encodedTable;
}
```

Does this start make sense?  Is it the best way to do this?  I'm not sure how to implement the switch statement for types, especially for List types.

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do?

Comment: Can you please clarify "encode int to int, string to string,.." portion? `Hashtable` stores objects, so not clear what other transformation you need to store field values obtained via reflection (already as `object`) into `Hashtable`.

Comment: @SLaks looks like attempt to implement `dynamic` in 1.x to me...

Comment: Okay, in that case, how do I check for List<T>, convert to ArrayList, and then store that in the hash table?  The int and string isn't important.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: If he was in 1.x, he wouldnt be asking how to deal with generic types.

Comment: Basically I am using someone else's library that encodes Hashtables and ArrayLists to JSON.

Comment: Why do you need to use something so painful to create JSON? Can you simply use JSON.Net instead (or even built-in converter if mapping is straight forward)?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Agreed - we use JSON.Net and it makes it easy to serialize stuff from .Net classes and collections to JSON and back.

Comment: I'm using Unity and JSON.Net doesn't work out of the box..

Comment: I've updated your question with your actual goal. While it is probably better idea to use newer library to convert o JSON you can try checking `encodedValue is IList` and recursively convert each element.